# Using Mongoose.js Model.Remove(conditions, callback) - remove successful but callback not being called

Tags: node.js, mongodb, callback, mongoose

I've simplified down to the following most basic possible version...

```
    UserModel.remove({ }, function (err) {
        console.log("inside callback");
    })
```

I've verified that the records are being removed but the callback is never called.

I've successfully added documents using

```
var user = new UserModel(req.body);

user.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return (next(err));
    } else {
        res.json(user);
    }
});
```

I've set up some tests and verified that the records are inserted using the mongodb shell.  Then verified that they are deleted when I call remove, so I know the database connection is good.  Everything works as expected except the callback is never called by remove.  I've even put some console.log statements in the save callback and it works as expected.

I'm using node 0.10.33, mongoose 4.0.4 and mongodb 2.6.6

Any ideas on what might be happening here?

Thanks in advance,

Jeff

OK, as expected, I'm being asked for more context.  The above was to keep it simple.  The context around the UserModel.remove call is the following...

```
var UserModel = require('mongoose').model('User');

exports.create = function (req, res, next) {
    var user = new UserModel(req.body);

    user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return (next(err));
        } else {
            res.json(user);
        }
    });
};

exports.list = function (req, res, next) {
    UserModel.find({}, function (err, users) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        } else {
            res.json(users);
        }
    });
};

exports.delete = function (req, res, next) {

        UserModel.remove({ }, function (err) {
            console.log("finished deleting single user");

        })

}
```

mongoose.js is...

```
var config = require('./config'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function (){
    var db = mongoose.connect(config.dbUri);

    require('../app/models/user.server.model');

    return db;
}
```

config.js is...

```
module.exports = {
    sessionSecret: 'developmentSessionSecret',
    dbUri: 'mongodb://localhost/test'
};
```

and finally, user.server.model.js is ...

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    username: String,
    password: String
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Here is my mocha test file too in case that helps at all...

```
var boot = require('../server').boot,
    shutdown = require('../server').shutdown,
    port = require('../server').port,
    superagent = require('superagent'),
    expect = require('chai').expect,
    baseUrl = 'http://localhost:' + port,
    Utility = require('../Utility');

describe('server', function () {

    before(function () {
        boot();
    });



    describe('homepage', function () {
        it('should respond to GET', function (done) {

            superagent
                .get(baseUrl)
                .end(function (err, res) {
                expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
                done();
            })
        })
    });

    describe('/users', function () {
        var url = baseUrl + "/users";

        var returnedJson,
            id;

        it('should respond when a JSON message is posted that matches the schema', function (done) {

            superagent
                    .post(url)
                    .send({ 'firstName': 'Jeff', 'lastName': 'Hegedus', 'email': 'jhegedus@centrifugeit.com', 'username': 'jhegedus', 'password': 'testpassword' })
                    .end(function (err, res) {
                expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
                returnedJson = res.text;
                done();
            })

        })

        it('should return the result of the insert with the _id populated', function () {

            var returnedObject = JSON.parse(returnedJson);
            id = returnedObject._id;
            expect(id).to.be.ok;

        })



        it('should respond to get', function (done) {
            superagent
                    .get(url)
                    .end(function (err, res) {
                expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
                done();
            })
        });


        // Delete by id
        it('should allow delete of the user created', function () {

            superagent
                    .del(url)
                    .set("id", id)
                    .end(function (err, res) {
                console.log("in response from delete");
                expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
                returnedJson = res.text;
                console.log("deleted " + returnedJson);
                done();
            })

        })


    })




    after(function () {
        shutdown();
    });

});
```

Oh, and in case you're wondering, the real delete function I'm working on is in this as the current state

```
exports.delete = function (req, res, next){
    var id = req.get("id");
    console.log("deleting id = " + id);

    if (id == null) {
        console.log("deleting all users");
        UserModel.remove({}, function (err, users){
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            } else {
                res.json(users);
            }
        })
    } else {

        UserModel.remove({ "_id": id }, function (err) {
            console.log("deleting single user");
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            } else {
                res.json(users);
            }
        })

    }
}
```

I knew better than to post the simple version.  Half tempted to post the whole thing to github so you can see how it all fits together.  ;-)

Comment: Please, show us the code around the `User.remove` call.

Comment: Hey @Rodrigo Medeiros, I posted the context.  I know it's a lot but I figured I would just get it all out there.

Comment: When you run your tests, what is the fail message for the delete user test?

Comment: It actually succeeds.  It just never prints the console.log message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't pass a `done` argument to your test callback, `mocha` doesn't wait for its completion, but it still executes it. You did:

```
it('should allow delete of the user created', function () {
  // your test
});
```

So, that's why your user data is being deleted, but you can't see anything logged in the console: the `delete` route is being called, the `UserModel.remove` is being executed, but the `mocha` execution is finishing without waiting for its return. Just pass the `done` callback:

```
it('should allow delete of the user created', function (done) {
  // your test
});
```

Comment: That was the problem.  Thank you!